# Generate a dynamic switch structure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, dynamically-generated

Is there a way you can create a dynamic generated switch statement? I will explain further, I have a table with all the possible coins. Every person has a table with their own coins. If you click on a coin a new action will happen in the php and you will be direct for example to `index.php?actie=Ripple`.

My code:

```
case "Ripple":
    if ($_SESSION["name"] == "d"){
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAllesD("XRP/BTC");
    }
    else{
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAlles("XRP/BTC");
    }
    Uitvoer::toonDeRippleTable($dataFromTransactions,"Ripple");
    break;
case "LiteCoin":
    if ($_SESSION["name"] == "d"){
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAllesD("LTC/BTC");
    }
    else{
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAlles("LTC/BTC");
    }
    Uitvoer::toonDeRippleTable($dataFromTransactions,"LiteCoin");
    break;
```

Is there a way that I need to do like a:

```
$alleCoins = $pol->getAlleCoinsYouBuyed()
foreach($alleCoins as $coinInfo){
case $coinInfo->Coinname :
if ($_SESSION["name"] == "d"){
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAllesD($coinInfo->Market);
    }
    else{
        $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAlles($coinInfo->Market);
    }
    Uitvoer::toonDeRippleTable($dataFromTransactions,$coinInfo->Coinname);
    break;
}
```

this code must be in the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
if ($_SESSION["name"] == "d"){
    $alleCoins = dataBaseTrade::getPoloniexInstantie()->getAlleCoinsYouBuyedD();
}
else {
    $alleCoins = dataBaseTrade::getPoloniexInstantie()->getAlleCoinsYouBuyed();
}
$searchNameArray = json_decode(json_encode($alleCoins), true);
$searchNameArray = array_column($searchNameArray, "Coinname" );
switch ($actie){
    case ($actie != "home" || "user"):
        $valueOfThePlaceInTheArray = array_search($actie,$searchNameArray);
        $thisCoin = $alleCoins[$valueOfThePlaceInTheArray];
        if ($_SESSION["name"] == "d"){
            $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAllesD($thisCoin->Market);
        }
        else{
            $dataFromTransactions = $pol->toonAlles($thisCoin->Market);
        }
        Uitvoer::toonDeRippleTable($dataFromTransactions,$thisCoin->Coinname);
        break;
}
```